# New-AzEventGridSubscription "The attempt to validate the provided endpoint" failed

Tags: azure, powershell, webhooks, azure-eventgrid

I created an endpoint in my C# code at /events path. If the event is of type "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent", i extract the ValidationCode and return 200 with a json object with validationResponse. I tested this using Postman, and everything appears to work, but when using "New-AzEventGridSubscription", it fails. Any ideas?

Here's the command I used, scrubbed of course.

`New-AzEventGridSubscription -ResourceGroup MyResourceGroupName -Endpoint https://requestb.in/19qlscd1/events -EventSubscriptionName EventSubscription1 -TopicName Topic1`

Sample Post:

```
[
{
"id": "531d4a96-d4c7-43d6-8b4c-e1ff9351b869",
"topic": "scrubbed",
"subject": "",
"data": {
"validationCode": "7062AAC0-656D-4C4C-BDD6-0FA673676D95",
"validationUrl": "scrubbed"
},
"eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
"eventTime": "2020-03-30T17:46:15.1827678Z",
"metadataVersion": "1",
"dataVersion": "2"
}
]
```

Sample Response:

```
{
"validationResponse": "7062AAC0-656D-4C4C-BDD6-0FA673676D95"
}
```

Here is my code to handle the Event. I've tested this using Ngrok, and it appears to work.

```
private void HandleEvent(IApplicationBuilder app) 
        { 
            app.Run(async context => 
            { 
                string content; 
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body)) 
                { 
                    content = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
                } 

                var eventGridEvents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventGridEvent[]>(content); 

                foreach (var eventGridEvent in eventGridEvents) 
                { 
                    if (eventGridEvent.EventType == "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent") 
                    { 
                        var eventDataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventGridEvent.Data); 
                        var eventData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubscriptionValidationEventData>(eventDataJson); 

                        var responseData = new SubscriptionValidationResponse() 
                        { 
                            ValidationResponse = eventData.ValidationCode 
                        }; 

                        context.Response.StatusCode = 200; 
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseData)); 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)eventGridEvent.Data); 
                        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(deserialized.GetType())) 
                        { 
                            eventGridEvent.Data = (IEnumerable<object>)deserialized; 
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                            eventGridEvent.Data = new List<object>() { deserialized }; 
                        } 

                        await HandleMessageListAsync(eventGridEvents.ToList()); 
                    } 
                } 

                context.Response.StatusCode = 200; 
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty); 
            }); 
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The payload delivered by event grid is an array with one event by default. Are you extracting the value from the object inside the array correctly? Also, I believe having some logs from your server would help to assure that the response returned when event grid is making the call would help.

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT yeah, sorry, my sample Post is missing the beginning bracket. I'll fix. Added my handling logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was my API was returned as "Chunked". Microsoft applied a patch to support "Chunked" responses, and now it works. :)